# How to save 3D position of all rendered pixels in to a file Unity3D?

Tags: image, unity-game-engine, position

I'm pretty new to Unity and I use this game engine for robotic purposes. I was wondering how I can save the 3D world position of the pixels rendered by my camera into an array and upload it to Python?

Answer (score 0):

I don't quite understand what you want to say by "the world position of the pixel", but maybe you can try this :

```
point = cam.ScreenToWorldPoint(new Vector2(x, y)); //For the pixel with coordinates x,y
```

I'm not really sure that (x,y) really is the xth row yth column of pixels, but try this and tell me if it doesn't work